# ExtJs, custom TextField's getValue() function not being called when form is submitted

Tags: javascript, forms, extjs, extjs3

I have a custom text field that extends `Ext.form.TextField` (ExtJs 3.1.1). I have overridden `getValue` to submit a calculated value instead of the raw value in the superclass. When calling `getValue` directly the return value is correct. However when submitting the parent form, `getValue` is not being called at all (debug messages in the `getValue` method do not appear in the console). How can I override the value returned when the form is submitted? Isn't `getValue` the correct method to override?

Here's the general layout of the class (I can't provide the actual code):

```
MyField = Ext.extend(Ext.form.Textfield, {
    constructor: function(config) {
        [initialize some basic variables....]
        MyField.superclass.constructor.call(this, config);
    },

    initComponent : function() {
         this.on('keypress', this.handler, this);
    },

    handler : function(field, event, args) {
         [set an internal value this.myValue based on superclass value]
    },

    getValue : function () {return this.myValue;}
});
```

The above is working fine in terms of calculating `myValue` and returning it when `getValue` is called. However when added in a form, the value in the `Ext.form.TextField` is being returned, and I have also noticed that `MyField.getValue` is not being called at all when `FormPanel.getForm().submit()` is called on the parent FormPanel object.

Comment: could you provide an exmaple of your code?

Comment: I can't share the code, but i'll add a example of what i'm trying to do

Comment: ExtJs 3.4 have a submitValue property, try this, add submitValue: true to your component's config. Unfortunatelly i have not found this version(3.1) in sencha documentation

Comment: submitValue defaults to true. The field is submitting that's not the problem, the value is taken from the superclass how can I override that?

Comment: it's good, then you must to correct your setValue, something like this: setValue: function(value) {MyField.superclass.setValue.call(this, value);}

Comment: That would display the internal value which must not be displayed. I need the user's input to be displayed and the hidden value to remain hidden

Comment: why? you have overriden getValue method

Comment: The displayed value (value in the superclass) is a masked version of the internal value, I have overridden getValue to return the internal unmasked value. If i call setValue on the superclass an put in it the unmasked value it would become visible to the user

Comment: Have you tried overriding `getRawValue` instead? I vaguely recall needing to do that on older Exts.

Comment: Yes I have, the weird thing was It got called when sumbit() was invoked, but the value submitted was the value in the superclass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can achieve what you're trying to do without overriding a lot more behavior.

If you debug into the submit action, you'll see the following in `Ext.form.Action.Submit`:

```
Ext.Ajax.request(Ext.apply(this.createCallback(o), {
    form:this.form.el.dom,
    url:this.getUrl(isGet),
    method: method,
    headers: o.headers,
    params:!isGet ? this.getParams() : null,
    isUpload: this.form.fileUpload
}));
```

Note that it passes the actual form DOM element (i.e. `this.form.el.dom`) which would contain your field's actual value, not your calculated value.

If you continue debugging, you'll see that within the call to `Ext.Ajax.request` the `form` parameter gets serialized via `Ext.lib.Ajax.serializeForm(form)`.  The resulting serialized value is passed into `Ext.lib.Ajax.request` as the `data` parameter.  That value is what is actually sent to the server.

Comment: Great detailed answer.